# How use wrapfigure in IEEE format

Tags: wrapfigure

[image]

I'm using Latex for my first time with IEEE and trying to put text, after an image and then more text. This is the best that I could do (see image), but the problem is that some piece of text goes in the right part with the Fig and I would like to have the next way
(I'm using texmaker)

texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext

```
             (centering Fig1)
```

texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext

UPDATE:

Using `\usepackage{float}` and

```
\begin{figure}[H]

\end{figure}
```

it works

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to achive? I assume you want the left column to just contain text, then a figure in the right column, more text and then a second figure? If the figures should be as wide as the text in the column, don't use `wrapfigure` but a simple `figure` environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks Zarko!. I start using "Figure" but as you say, it throw the image at the final of the /section. I want to achive that write a paragraph, then a fig, then another paragrah , another fig and so on . But the imagen using the whole space without text in the left. Thanks for your answer Leandriis

Comment: Please provide an example of your document (with dummy text) which reproduce your problem. From your image of code is not visible, how you write your document. Example should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the figure to be as wied as both columns combined? If so, tabke a look at the `figure*` environment.

Comment: This looks like a job for \afterpage (which also works after columns).

Comment: Hi guys! now i understood why u could not helpme , i didn´t explain it soo well, but i solved it using [figure] , i´ll upload a update in the question with the solution